# How can I insert space programatically at the end of Spanned String in android?

Tags: android

I have the following string-

```
SpannedString line = (SpannedString) TextUtils.concat(LastWordSaved,content);
etMessageBox.setText(line);
```

How can insert space programatically at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically do `etMessageBox.setText(line+" ")` or

```
line = (SpannedString)TextUtils.concat(line + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this be the solution?

```
SpannedString line = (SpannedString) TextUtils.concat(LastWordSaved+" ",content);
etMessageBox.setText(line);
```